# Firestore security rules: functions and if statements

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Stuck with security rules.

I have custom claims for roles like this:

```
request.auth.token.accessRules[ownerId].roles
```

In my case not every user has `accessRules` and not every user has roles for the specific ownerId. For those cases I need to return an empty list.

My initial naive approach was to specify the following function:

```
function userRoles(ownerId) {
    return request.auth.token.accessRules[ownerId].roles || []
}
```

But that fails with the following error:

> Property accessRules is undefined on object

Ok, fair enough.

I can check if it's defined using `request.auth.token.get('accessRules', null) != null`

So that function transformed into

```
function rolesExistsFor(ownerId) {
    return request.auth.token.get('accessRules', null) != null && request.auth.token.accessRules.get('ownerId', null) != null
}
function userRoles(ownerId) {
    return rolesExistsFor(ownerId) && request.auth.token.accessRules[ownerId].roles || []
}
```

But that fails again:

> Type error. Received: [list] Expected: [bool]

And here I realised that in firestore rules logical operations force both operands to be bool and I can't really return anything rather than bool in this case (as one would normally expect in something like javascript).

How do I safely check and return default values?

Is there any syntax I'm missing or I can't really do that?

On the other hand, when a claim is not there, the rules will crash and give "access denied" which is the expected end result. Is that normal to keep it like that then?

Comment: How do you set the Custom Claims (Share the code pls)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I set them using the admin SDK—standard staff. However, the focus isn't on the correctness of the claims but on handling various scenarios in rules. Doug addressed this below, resolving my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal to accept that rule evaluations that generate an error to simply deny the request.  You don't need to check for any errors unless you want to make a decision about what to do next with that error. And there is no real downside to allowing the failure to happen.

Comment: Got it, thanks Doug. I suspected this and searched the docs for proof. While not explicitly mentioned, the examples imply it. It's good to have firsthand confirmation.